# Do electric tank-less water heater require flushing and how do one do it?

Tags: water-heater

On this [site](http://www.waterheaterrescue.com/Longevity/tankless-water-heaters.html), it says:

> Because electric tankless still "lime up," and the sediment has to be cleaned out periodically or they may fail.

So, do electric tank-less water heater really require cleaned out and how do one do it?

Comment: Presumably this is a point of use electric tankless water heater and so it probably does not have special valves to allow descaling with white vinegar.  Or does it? If not, you would have to disconnect the heater to descale it. You would then connect a pump to circulate white vinegar through the heater. Do you want to go through this trouble? What does the manufacturer recommend?